# How can I get Silverlight 4 Tools to work in Web Developer 2010 Express?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit, wrappanel, dockpanel

I installed **Windows 7**.

I then installed **Web Developer 2010 Express** [from here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/) with the **Web Platform Installer**.

I then installed the the **April 15 release of Silverlight 4 Toolkit** [from here](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/43528).

I then added this **reference**:

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/ijk0lm.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/ijk0lm.png)

Then in my XAML, I reference it like this but it gives me **no intellisense and tells me that I am missing an assembly reference**:

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/cd4vrj.png](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/cd4vrj.png)

**update:**

```
xmlns:tk="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
```

doesn't work either, even after a rebuild

**What do I have to do to use the Silverlight 4 Toolkit in Web Developer 2010 Express?**

## Addendum:

So I tested it out again with Silverlight 3 in Web Developer Express 2008 on another computer and it does indeed work the way I remember, so **why doesn't it work the this way in Silverlight 4 and what do I need to change to get it to work?**:

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/14eo9k7.jpg](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/14eo9k7.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You should add a reference to Microsoft.Windows.Controls not System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit then this

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Windows.Controls"

<controls:DockPanel />
```

Comment: that sounds good, but it still says controls:DockPanel cannot be found, seems the problem is the only component name I have in the Add Reference box that starts with "Microsoft" is "Microsoft.VisualBasic" will try to reinstall the silverlight 4 toolkit

Comment: Sound good, this might help you http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/justinangel/archive/2008/10/30/silverlight-toolkit-dockpanel.aspx

Comment: after unstalling everything that has to do with silverlight, then reinstalling the silverlight 4 tools (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=bf5ab940-c011-4bd1-ad98-da671e491009&displaylang=en) and the silverlight 4 toolkit (http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/43528) I still don't see Microsoft.Windows.Controls in the Add Reference box

Comment: added reference to: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Toolkit\Apr10\Bin\System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.dll still has same problem, no intellisense and says reference is missing

Comment: Sorry I cant give it a try right now, let me know you figure it out

Comment: I'm getting closer, I tried it again on my other computer which still has web developer express 2008 with silverlight 3 and it worked the way I am trying it here, so I just need to figure out how the referencing of the silverlight 4 toolkit deviates from that of silverlight 3 (posted screenshot above).

Answer (score 0):

ok I got it to work with this namespace:

```
xmlns:tk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
```

but it unfortunately only gives me partial intellisense which [**leads to this question**.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661814/what-does-silverlight-4-tools-only-give-partial-intellisense)