# Why does Silverlight 4 Tools only give partial intellisense?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I finally got Silverlight 4 Toolkit installed , referenced and working after the [difficulty of finding the right namespace described in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661010/how-can-i-get-silverlight-4-tools-to-work-in-web-developer-2010-express).

But intellisense doesn't work fully: after I type "`tk:`", it doesn't pop up the various controls I have available, but if I type a control name out, e.g. `DockPanel`, then it works, as shown below. It will even give me intellisense after I type tk:DropPanel, which is odd.

**How can I get intellisense to work in all cases for the Silverlight 4 Toolkit?**

I can imagine I need another namespace, but [this site](http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2010/04/15/alive-and-kickin-new-silverlight-4-toolkit-released-with-today-s-silverlight-4-rtw.aspx) says that this reference:

> is now all you need (and will be
>   automatically used by both Visual
>   Studio and Blend)

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/q02bav.jpg](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/q02bav.jpg)

Here is a screenshot from **Silverlight 3 Toolkit intellisense** which has always worked well in both vs2008 and web dev express 2008:

[alt text http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/196ufid.jpg](http://www.deviantsart.com/upload/196ufid.jpg)

Comment: Maybe you can't get full intellisense? I've noticed the same kind of behaviour from VS2008, often you won't get intellisense after typing the namespace prefix.

Comment: It has always worked for me well in Silverlight 3 Toolkit, I posted a screenshot of it above.

Comment: I have the same issue with the toolkit and sometimes, the XAML editor in general. No rhyme or reason for it, just doesn't always trigger the intellisense window. It happened after I installed the toolkit though.

Answer (score 3):

Confirmed.

This appears to be an issue with the Silverlight Toolkit assemblies, as this does work for the SDK assemblies.

[Print Screen http://img162.imageshack.us/img162/9004/noitellisensetoolkit.png](http://img162.imageshack.us/img162/9004/noitellisensetoolkit.png)

If I were you I'd file a bug up on connect @ [Microsoft Connect](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=connect.microsoft.com&wreply=https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/CreateFeedbackForm.aspx?FeedbackFormConfigurationID=3785&FeedbackType=1&stoAI=10&wp=MBI_FED_SSL&wlcxt=microsoft$microsoft$microsoft)

In the meanwhile, I'd recommend considering using [Resharper](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+5.0+Nightly+Builds) to supply your Visual Studio intellisense as using the Ctrl+Space key combination in resharper does provide intellisense at this point.

Comment: thanks, interesting to know it seems to be a general error, I tried to post there at Microsoft Connect but got technical issue: "If you believe you have reached this page in error, click the Help link at the top of the page to report the issue and include the ID in your e-mail." but the help link has no option to send an e-mail, so gave up on that route. :-(

Comment: thanks, I have exactly the same problem with VS 2010 RTM. After installing SL 4 Toolkit I've lost intellisense on all non-sdk controls.